# how to convert yuyv to rgb code to yuv420 to rgb

Tags: c, yuv

I have been trying to find code for yuv420 to rgb but nothing is working for me. I have already a code for yuyv to rgb which is working. So i want to make changes in this code so that it can work as yuv to rgb.

Here is yuyv to rgb code:

```
static void YUV2RGB(const unsigned char y, const unsigned char u,const unsigned char v, unsigned char* r,
                unsigned char* g, unsigned char* b)
{
   const int y2 = (int)y;
   const int u2 = (int)u - 128;
   const int v2 = (int)v - 128;
   //std::cerr << "YUV=("<<y2<<","<<u2<<","<<v2<<")"<<std::endl;

   // This is the normal YUV conversion, but
   // appears to be incorrect for the firewire cameras
   //   int r2 = y2 + ( (v2*91947) >> 16);
   //   int g2 = y2 - ( ((u2*22544) + (v2*46793)) >> 16 );
   //   int b2 = y2 + ( (u2*115999) >> 16);
   // This is an adjusted version (UV spread out a bit)

   int r2 = y2 + ((v2 * 37221) >> 15);
   int g2 = y2 - (((u2 * 12975) + (v2 * 18949)) >> 15);
   int b2 = y2 + ((u2 * 66883) >> 15);
   //std::cerr << "   RGB=("<<r2<<","<<g2<<","<<b2<<")"<<std::endl;

   // Cap the values.
   *r = CLIPVALUE(r2);
   *g = CLIPVALUE(g2);
   *b = CLIPVALUE(b2);
}


static void yuyv2rgb(char *YUV, char *RGB, int NumPixels)
{
   int i, j;
   unsigned char y0, y1, u, v;
   unsigned char r, g, b;

   for (i = 0, j = 0; i < (NumPixels << 1); i += 4, j += 6)
   {
      y0 = (unsigned char)YUV[i + 0];
      u = (unsigned char)YUV[i + 1];
      y1 = (unsigned char)YUV[i + 2];
      v = (unsigned char)YUV[i + 3];
      YUV2RGB(y0, u, v, &r, &g, &b);
      RGB[j + 0] = r;
      RGB[j + 1] = g;
      RGB[j + 2] = b;
      YUV2RGB(y1, u, v, &r, &g, &b);
      RGB[j + 3] = r;
      RGB[j + 4] = g;
      RGB[j + 5] = b;
   }
}
```

I want to convert this code to yuv420 to rgb thats why i want to know the changes i should make to make it work.
thank you

Comment: hm.. maybe you can check videoconvert source code from gstreamer..